# Phpunit skeletongenerator Issue with autogenerating test methods based upon @assertregexp annotation

Tags: unit-testing, annotations, phpunit, assertions

I've been having some issues.

If I create test methods based on the following class:

```
<?php
class Calc
{
    /**
     * @assert (0, 0) == 0
     * @assert (0, 1) == 1
     */
    public function add($a, $b)
    {
        return $a + $b;
    }
}
```

... then I get:

```
<?php

/**
 * Generated by PHPUnit_SkeletonGenerator on 2015-09-07 at 10:34:19.
 */
require_once '../Calc.php';
class CalcTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    /**
     * @var Calc
     */
    protected $object;

    protected function setUp() {
        $this->object = new Calc;
    }

    protected function tearDown() {

    }

    /**
     * Generated from @assert (0, 0) == 0.
     *
     * @covers Calc::add
     * @group production
     */
    public function testAdd() {
        $this->assertEquals(
                0
                , $this->object->add(0, 0)
        );
    }

    /**
     * Generated from @assert (0, 1) == 1.
     *
     * @covers Calc::add
     * @group production
     * @group development
     */
    public function testAdd2() {
        $this->assertEquals(
                1
                , $this->object->add(0, 1)
        );
    }
}
```

...and this is cool. It's works like a charme.

BUT if I want to use the annotation @assertRegExp(expectedRegex, string pattern) in another class:

```
<?php
class RegexExample {

    private $input;

    public function __construct() {}

    /**
     * @assertRegExp ('/^[0-9]*$/', $this->object->setDigit('Mowgli'))
     * @assertRegExp ('/^[0-9]*$/', $this->object->setDigit('79579534'))
     */
    public function setDigit($inp) {
        $this->input= $inp;
    }
}
```

... when I create test methods now the test class is generated, but it doesnt implement the test methods:

```
<?php

/**
 * Generated by PHPUnit_SkeletonGenerator on 2015-09-18 at 13:22:27.
 */
class RegexExampleTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    /**
     * @var User
     */
    protected $object;

    protected function setUp() {
        $this->object = new User;
    }

    protected function tearDown() {

    }

    /**
     * @covers User::setDigit
     * @todo   Implement testSetDigit().
     */
    public function testSetDigit() {
        // Remove the following lines when you implement this test.
        $this->markTestIncomplete(
                'This test has not been implemented yet.'
        );
    }
}
```

The whole point is to get test methods like this one:

```
public function testSetDigit() {
        $this->assertRegExp(
                '/^[0-9]*$/'
                ,   $this->object->setDigit('Mowgli')
        );
    }
```

... which works, but if I want to do fx n numbers af test methods I would rather use annotations in my respective object class than copy/paste and edit approach.

If I find a solution I'll post it here.

I'm a noob at phpunit, so could be a lame noob mistake I made. If so, sry in advance.

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder from where you got the idea that @assertRegexp is a valid assertion annotation. I searched the repository of the subproject "PHPUnit SkeletonGenerator" and did not find any reference that suggests you can use a regular expression: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-skeleton-generator/search?p=1&q=assert&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93

Additionally, your assertion annotation does not make sense. These annotations are meant to provide working unit test assertions. First, your tested function does not return anything, so there is no value the regex can be used on. Second, you don't provide a means to indicate that the regex assertion for the string "Mowgli" should fail - at least that's my expectation for this case.

Remember that the availability or absence of features depends on the version you are using, so please indicate which version of PHPUnit and the skeleton generator you are using.